# How can UNCLOSED connection be found in OC4J/Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g, connection-pooling, oc4j

I fixed and use Connection Pool to get the DB Connection from JSP to Oracle Database now.

But then I found out from the OC4J console at once that there are many UNCLOSED/NOT-CLOSED connection.

I am using OC4J 9.0.4.1 and Oracle 10g. Is there any effective way to find out the location or area that the connection is not closed.

In addition, I would like to know the followings:

1) The UNCLOSED connection means the Connection or ResultSet or Statment ?
2) IF Connection for the ResultSet and Statement is closed, the corresponding ResultSet and Statement are closed automatically too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect that this is easiest to detect on the server side - one assumes (!) that there is a 'show me all the open connections' report or command on the server that should show up a list of those connections together with the last executed SQL on that connection (am coming from the MSSQL side of things here - this doesn't sound like too much of a stretch, tho').

Unclosed means that the connection has not been closed.

Comment: Any suggestion or hint then ?

Comment: Sure - take a look @ the server state and get a list of open connections there + the SQL that was last executed on each - I'd expect you'll see a lot of the same SQL if you've forgotten to close a connection somewhere.

Comment: Yes fire up SQL Developer, connect to the database, see database sessions and you can see the last SQL for each session.

Comment: I am running SQLDeveloper now. I am checking the Tools-->Monitor Sessions

Comment: I am running SQLDeveloper now. I am checking the Tools-->Monitor Sessions

Comment: I saw a list of connections. But it didn't show whether those connections are closed or not. In addition, where can I check the corresponding SQL statement for each connetion ?